# How can I spawn a process in nodejs with unknown command type?

Tags: node.js, stdio, spawn

I'm trying to pass-through a command in node js received from elsewhere.  For the sake of keeping the question simple, imagine there's a function that returns the following (though I have no way to know that ahead of time):

`echo "your password is test" & ssh root@1.1.1.1`

I would like to take the text above and run it correctly.  Because `ssh` uses stdin, `exec` won't do the trick, and `spawn` seems to be the best option.  But because spawn expects a command and list of arguments, it's not very well suited to something with an `&` in it.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to just run:

```
const command = mysteryCommand();  // echo "your password is test" & ssh root@1.1.1.1

spawn(command, {
  stdio: "inherit",
});
```

But so far this hasn't proven to work.  Other things I've tried include:

`spawn(command, { stdio: "ignore", detached: true})` // errored

`spawn(command, { stdio: "inherit", shell: true})`  // outputs, but input appears not to work

*How can I run my mystery command in a way that inherits stdio?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue.

First off, the answer to the question above is `spawn(command, { stdio: "inherit", shell: true})`.  Works just fine.

And the issue I was having was that the password part of ssh does not use stdin/out.  It uses something else.

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1157#issuecomment-7339123